# Character in need to steer his boat properly!

Tags: animation, rigging, parent, fcurves

I have a character on top of his boat, the boat has noise mod on its F curves rotation axis. Character is Rigged and parented to boat and holding steering wheel. Character itself has a bit of noise on the torso rotation controller (to simulate displacement caused by boat). The problem I'm having with this is that even using IK on hands controller to steer the steering wheel, the noise mod (only applied to torso) is making the hands going off the steering wheel itself.
Is there a way to kind of parent the hand to the steering wheel but leaving the rest untouched?
How would you solve this?
If I was not clear please tell.
Ideally it looks like I should parent the character to boat, and also the character hands to steering wheel. Is this even possible?

[image]

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: From the text of your question, it is not clear how you let the hand control the steering wheel. What is the hierarchy there? How did you connect the two?

Comment: I would create an armature for the boat with a *root bone > steering bone > wheel bone* so you can move & tilt the boat and rotate the wheel. Then use a *Child Of* bone constraint for the hand IK. It will become a child of the wheel ("the man grabs the wheel"). The influence value can be adjusted by keyframes to release the grip ("the man lets go of the steering wheel."). Technically, the wheel rotation controls the hand, not vice versa. To make the man stand on the boat you need to add a *Child Of* (object) constraint to the man's armature/*rig* with the boat's root bone as the target.

Comment: if you want a "special" solution for your specific case, pls provide blend file, because this depends heavily on your settings of your rig. Otherwise you will get "general" solution proposals which might not suit to your blend file.

Comment: Thanks @Blunder and @ Chris. I used the 'Child of' bone constraint with 2 empties (one for each hand controller) parented to the steering wheel. So now I control the hands directly with the wheel. Happy days. Thank you for your time and inputs

Answer (score 0):

After inputs received in the comments, I realized the easiest way to do it is by using on the hand controller bone, the "child of" bone constraint that target an empty (I used 1 for each hand) that is parented to the boat steering wheel.
Now I can control the rig just turning the steering wheel and the rig can take any noise mod while the hands still maintaining their position.